# Matplotlib custom style error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set the plotting style in matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib

print matplotlib.__version__

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Output:

> 1.5.1
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'

So the version of my matplotlib is > 1.4 but style still doesnt work. I did confirm that the style folder is in `site-packages`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.version
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```